# Download Fasta protein sequences as a file from the selected categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have the following function in Django to download the Fasta sequences (protein) through the selected categories as a file. This works well. I would like to improve the following script.

```
import textwrap
from io import StringIO
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from database.models import PesticidalProteinDatabase

def download_data(request):
    """List the categories for download."""

    categories = \
        PesticidalProteinDatabase.objects.order_by(
            'name').values_list('name').distinct()
    category_prefixes = []
    for category in categories:
        prefix = category[0][:3]
        if prefix not in category_prefixes:
            category_prefixes.append(prefix)

    context = {
        'proteins': PesticidalProteinDatabase.objects.all(),
        'category_prefixes': category_prefixes
    }
    return render(request, 'database/download_category.html', context)



def download_category(request, category=None):
    """Download the fasta sequences for the category."""

    context = {
        'proteins': PesticidalProteinDatabase.objects.all()
    }
    category = category.title()
    file = StringIO()
    data = list(context.get('proteins'))

    for item in data:
        if category in item.name:
            fasta = textwrap.fill(item.fastasequence, 80)
            str_to_write = f">{item.name}\n{fasta}\n"
            file.write(str_to_write)
        else:
            pass

    if 'All' in category:
        for item in data:
            fasta = textwrap.fill(item.fastasequence, 80)
            str_to_write = f">{item.name}\n{fasta}\n"
            file.write(str_to_write)

    response = HttpResponse(file.getvalue(), content_type="text/plain")
    download_file = f"{category}_fasta_sequences.txt"
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename='+download_file
    response['Content-Length'] = file.tell()
    return response
```

The template data

```html
{% extends "database/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<!doctype html>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p> <b> Download the fasta sequences by categories </b> </p>
      {% for prefix in category_prefixes %}
        <li>
            <a href="/download_category_{{ prefix|lower }}" >
              {{ prefix }}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>

        <li>
          <a href="/download_category_all" > All
        </li>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

The url data

```
from django.urls import path
from database import views

path('download_data/', views.download_data, name='download_data'),
path('download_category_<str:category>', views.download_category,
 name='download_category'),
```

Comment: It's fine you want a focus on this particular function, but I'm sure there's more to the script. Could you add that as well?

Comment: I have added the script. Also here is the full [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/228912/181325)

Comment: @catuf How is the program used, though? Also, I believe the indentation in your post is broken.

Comment: I forgot to mention that anything more than minor optimizations will require other parts of the program.

Comment: Can you add all your imports?